# Rails 3 Cache Dump error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use Rails 3.0.5 with Ruby 1.9.2 for an app. In my development mode, I have configured caching ON.

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :file_store, "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/cache"
```

And in one of the actions, I have this line of code,

```
@featured_players = Rails.cache.fetch("featured-players") { Player.featured(8) }
```

The above line returns the following error

```
TypeError (no marshal_dump is defined for class Mutex):
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:100:in `dump'
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:100:in `block in write_entry'
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:20:in `atomic_write'
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:100:in `write_entry'
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:135:in `write_entry'
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/cache.rb:364:in `block in write'
  activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/cache.rb:519:in `instrument'
```

`featured` is a class method of Player model that returns an array of players as a result of a db query. Its just a plain old array.

What seems to be the error.. I have tried several approaches to analyze this, but none worked. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cache is using standard [marshalling](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) to cache your objects. One of the objects that you're trying to serialize has a [Mutex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Mutex.html) in it but you can't serialize something that is little more than a bit of runtime state:

> Some objects cannot be dumped: if the objects to be dumped include bindings, procedure or method objects, instances of class IO, or singleton objects, a TypeError will be raised.

The problem is that some things only exist as runtime information and they cannot be recreated automatically.

You have a thread mutex somewhere in your Player and Marshal has no way of automatically serializing a mutex. You're going to have to implement your own serialization; there are two methods of doing this outlined in the [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) documentation:

- Implement `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` methods.
- Implement `_dump` and `_load` methods.

You'll probably want to go with `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` as they're the easiest.

Comment: thanks for explaining. So.. do  I need to create FeaturedPlayerCached class, and write methods marshal_dump and marshal_load in it.. ??

Comment: but the object that I'm dumping is an array of player objects => Im just dumping an Array which is very much marshable (if thats the right word for it)

Comment: Something inside your Player object has a Mutex. Could be a parent class, could be inside one of the attributes. You would put the `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` methods right in your Player class.

Answer (score 3):

Are you *sure* that it's an array, and not an ActiveRecord relation?  I've had this error, and it only went away after I converted it to an array. So, my code

```
Model.joined_model.where(blah)
```

had to become

```
Model.joined_model.where(blah).to_a
```

and away it went!